# replaceWith() and second jQuery function

Tags: jquery, forms, replacewith

I'm pretty new to jquery but I'm trying to do the following:
Click a link, replaceWith() a form and click the submit in the form triggers a second jquery function and ajax call and another replaceWith().

These are the two functions

```
$(function addtop10fromuserpage() {
    $(".addshowtotop10").click(function () {
        var button = $(this);
        button.replaceWith('<form><input class="addtop10userinput" type="text" name="seriesname" /><input type="submit" class="button small addtop10usersubmit" value="Add" /></form>');
    });
});


$(function addtop10fromuserpageshowadd() {
    $(".addtop10usersubmit").click(function () {
        var button = $(this);

        var position = button.closest(".top-rating").find(".top-rating-text").html();
        alert('position');
    });
});
```

Bascially, both functions are fine if they are called separately but if I call the second function from the replacewith form, it doesn't work. Why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the elements are created dynamically you need to use event delegation based handlers

```
$(function addtop10fromuserpage() {
    $(document).on('click', ".addshowtotop10", function () {
        var button = $(this);
        button.replaceWith('<form><input class="addtop10userinput" type="text" name="seriesname" /><input type="submit" class="button small addtop10usersubmit" value="Add" /></form>');
    });
});


$(function addtop10fromuserpageshowadd() {
    $(document).on('click', ".addtop10usersubmit", function () {
        var button = $(this);

        var position = button.closest(".top-rating").find(".top-rating-text").html();
        alert('position');
    });
});
```